# SQL query to only return a row based on fluid conditions

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I know this is possible but am unsure how to set this up.
Basically I am needing to pull data for each employee but only if it meets certain criteria based on a few different dates.

For instance, if the employee was assigned to a company before 6/1 they get counted automatically.

If the employee was assigned to a company after 6/1 they only get counted IF they have a review with that company after the date they were assigned(ie, they are assigned on 6/25 and have a review on 7/1...this should be counted. If for instance they were assigmed on 6/25 and the review happened on 6/15 they would not count for this employee)

If the employee gets removed from a company before 4/1 they dont get counted. If they are removed on or after 4/1 it counts.

So the key columns are Created Date of the review,  Start Date and End Date from the employee-customer table.

I believe this would need to either be some type of subquery which returns the start date for the employee with that customer and then compares the review date based on a Case statement evaluating this date versus the review date but I am unsure exactly how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Table Structure/Data below:

**Employee-Customer Table**

```
ID    EmpID   CustID  StartDate   EndDate
1       4       10    10/1/2017   2/21/2018
2       4       11    10/1/2017   7/31/2018
3       4       15    10/1/2017   4/8/2018
4       4       17    6/1/2018    NULL (means still active with this employee)
5       4       19    5/18/2018   NULL
```

**Customer Data Table**

```
ID    CustID   ActivityDate   Task
1       10       1/13/2018    Review
3       15       4/2/2018     Review
4       17       6/25/2018    Review
5       17       6/13/2018    Client Engagement
6       17       6/29/2018    Client Engagement
7       19       5/25/2018    Client Engagement
8       19       6/28/2018    Review
```

So for the this example, I want a query that brings back the following customer ID's with data based on the criteria:

- 10: This customer does **NOT** get returned because the customer was removed from the employee prior to the 4/1 cutoff date.
- 11: This customer **DOES** get returned because the employee has had the customer past the 5/31 cutoff date, even though there is no review for the customer
- 15: This customer **DOES** get returned because the employee had the customer past the 4/1 cutoff date before it was removed from them.
- 17: The client Engagement from 6/29/2018 **DOES** get returned but the client engagement from 6/13/2018 does **NOT** get returned because it happened BEFORE the review was done with this client(effectively when an employee Start Date for a customer is PAST 5/31 the activity only counts AFTER they have had a review with that customer---all activity that takes place prior to this review date gets ignored)
- 19: The Client Engagement **DOES** get returned in this case because the employee was assigned to them before 6/1, so any activity counts regardless of if a review was done prior to the other item happening.

Hopefully this explanation and breakdown makes sense.

UPDATE: Here are the table scripts and expected results:

```
CREATE TABLE Cust_Employee(

Cust_Emp_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

Cust_ID int NOT NULL,

Emp_ID int NULL,

Start_Date datetime NULL,

End_Date datetime NULL,

CONSTRAINT PK_Cust_Employee PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

(

Cust_Emp_ID ASC

)WITH (PAD INEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON PRIMARY

)ON PRIMARY

GO

CREATE TABLE Cust_Data(

Cust_Data_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

Cust_ID int NULL,

Activity_Date datetime NULL,

Task VARCHAR(50) NULL

)

CONSTRAINT PK_Client_Data PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

(

Cust_Data_ID ASC

)WITH (PAD INEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON PRIMARY

)ON PRIMARY

GO

INSERT INTO Cust_Employee VALUES(4, 10, '10/1/2017', '2/21/2018')

INSERT INTO Cust_Employee VALUES(4, 11, '10/1/2017', '7/31/2018')

INSERT INTO Cust_Employee VALUES(4, 15, '10/1/2017', '4/8/2018')

INSERT INTO Cust_Employee VALUES(4, 17, '6/1/2018', NULL)

INSERT INTO Cust_Employee VALUES(4, 19, '5/18/2018', NULL)

INSERT INTO Cust _Data VALUES(10, '1/13/2018', 'Review')

INSERT INTO Cust _Data VALUES(15, '4/2/2018', 'Review')

INSERT INTO Cust _Data VALUES(17, '6/25/2018', 'Review')

INSERT INTO Cust _Data VALUES(17, '6/13/2018', 'Client Engagement')

INSERT INTO Cust _Data VALUES(17, '6/29/2018', 'Client Engagement')

INSERT INTO Cust _Data VALUES(19, '5/25/2018', 'Client Engagement')

INSERT INTO Cust _Data VALUES(19, '6/28/2018', 'Review')
```

Expected Results:

[image]

Comment: Sample data and expected output will help

Comment: Please post table structure.

Comment: Added table structure and expected results to return.

Comment: @Gaurav any help on this?

Comment: I think I can help you with CASE conditions and probably CTE's but... still don't understand well what you need. First, please, provide DDL for your tables and also what is the expected result. Also, when you refer to dates (e.g. 10: ...to the 4/1 cutoff date") please, specify the full date, otherwise it is confusing why should or not appear in the results.

Comment: You've posted sample data (not as DDL and DML though), but we don't have your expected results. We really need both.

Comment: @AngelM. OK, here is basically what needs to happen.  Each employee has customers they are responsible for during specified start and end dates(end date can be null meaning its an active client). However, there are also certain conditions around whether the data should "count" or not.  The first condition states that if an employee ends a relationship with a customer before 4/1/2018, this data does not count(ie, NO data for this customer counts for this employee). The 2nd condition states that if an employee ends a relationship with a customer after 6/1/2018 ALL data counts for this customer.

Comment: @AngelM.The 3rd condition states that if an employee STARTS a relationship with a customer after 6/1/2018 ONLY activity that happens after the date of the initial Review Counts(see Cust_ID 17 in the bullet point explanation for this example).

Comment: @Larnu the bullet points contain the expected results

Comment: @MattE I have found a better way of finding the correct rows. The good thing of the new solution is that it allows an easy debug as it shows which rule has been applied. If any bug, can be discovered easily and then fixed.

Comment: When I ran the DDL and DML it looks like the EMP_ID, and CUST_ID fields are populated the wrong way around in the Cust_Employee table.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if I understood all your request. In fact, I am missing something as the results that I obtain are not exactly the same than you.
The code that I have prepared:

```
SELECT E.Cust_ID AS Emp_ID, E.Emp_ID AS Cust_ID, E.Start_Date, E.End_Date, 
        MAX(D.Activity_Date) AS Activity_Date, D.Task
    FROM Cust_Employee E
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Cust_Data D
        ON E.Emp_ID = D.Cust_ID
    WHERE COALESCE(E.End_Date, GETDATE()) > '20180401'
    GROUP BY 
            E.Cust_ID, E.Emp_ID, E.Start_Date, E.End_Date, 
            D.Task
    ORDER BY E.Cust_ID;[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

So, my query shows an extra row for Emp 19, not sure what is the condition that will eliminate, if you clarify myself I will correct the response.

### I have found another solution more refined that it is clearer and it works very well at least for the set of data provided with the advantage that it is very easy to maintain.

First, I have to recognise that the requirements for me are not 100% clear because are based in examples what is usual in real life. It is necessary to identify clearly the business rules that have to be applied and the sequence (order) that need to be applied. 
So, based in my guess I have built the following solution. The advantage of this solution is that it is very easy to debug as:

1. **Each rule is identified with a number** that can be shown in debug mode (ommited if required afterwards) and is telling which rule has been applied
2. The **rules are applied sequencially**, so, if one rule makes a record to be shown, rest of rules will not be applied. It is because that it is important the order that the rules are checked
3. **Negative number** for a rule shows that the rule means the **record should not be shown**.

:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT E.Cust_ID AS Emp_ID, E.Emp_ID AS Cust_ID, 
           E.Start_Date, E.End_Date, 
        MAX(D.Activity_Date) AS Activity_Date, D.Task,
        CASE 
            -- RULE -1: Removed Prior to 4/1 cutoff date
            WHEN E.End_Date < '20180401'                        THEN -1

            --  RULE 1: If the employee has had the customer past the 5/31 cutoff date, even though there is no review for the customer
            WHEN E.End_Date > '20180531'                        THEN 1

            --  RULE 2: If the employee had the customer past the 4/1 cutoff date before it was removed from them
            WHEN D.Activity_Date > '20180401' AND D.Activity_Date <= E.End_Date THEN 2

            --   RULE -2: Client engagement from 6/13/2018 does NOT get returned because it happened BEFORE the review was done with this client
            WHEN D.Task = 'Client Engagement' 
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Cust_Data D2 WHERE D2.Cust_ID = E.Emp_ID AND D2.Task = 'Review' AND D2.Activity_Date <= D.Activity_Date)
                THEN -2

            --   RULE 12: If the employee was assigned to a company before 6/1 they get counted automatically.
            WHEN E.Start_Date <= '20180601'                     THEN 12

            --  RULE 14: If EndDate later than June-1-2018
            WHEN  COALESCE(E.End_Date, GETDATE()) > '20180601'  THEN 14

            -- RULE 0: Other cases
            ELSE 0 

        END AS [Rule]
    FROM Cust_Employee E
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Cust_Data D
        ON E.Emp_ID = D.Cust_ID
        --AND D.Activity_Date > '20180401'

    GROUP BY 
            E.Cust_ID, E.Emp_ID, E.Start_Date, E.End_Date, 
            D.Task, D.Activity_Date
    ) 
SELECT Emp_ID, Cust_ID, Start_Date, End_Date, Activity_Date, Task, [Rule]
    FROM CTE
    WHERE [Rule] > 0
    ORDER BY Cust_ID, Start_Date, Activity_Date;
```

The best of this method is that it **calculates & shows the Rule** that has been applied, so, it can be debugged very easily as the query shows which rule has been applied. If the order of rulesor some rule is incorrect, it can be detected very quickly and fixed. The same applies for future changes as normally these rules based on dates do change very often and we need an easy way to maintain the code.
Finally, I hope that this exercise will give some ideas for future developments as traceability and supportability is very important when creating code.

Answer (score 2):

For such complex logics, I would advise for CTE statements in order to create subgroups of rows that are eligible to appear in the final result set, in order to have a cleaner query to create/maintain and creating positive/negative rules, like so:

```
;WITH AssignedBefore as
(
    --if the employee was assigned to a company before 6/1 they get counted automatically.
    SELECT Cust_ID, Emp_ID
    FROM Cust_Employee
    WHERE Start_Date <= '20180601'
),
AssignedReviewed as
(
    --If the employee was assigned to a company after 6/1 they only get counted IF they have a review with that company after the date they were assigned
    SELECT Cust_ID, Emp_ID
    FROM Cust_Employee E
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 1 as Exist
        FROM Cust_Data D
        WHERE D.Cust_ID = E.Cust_ID
        AND D.Task = 'Review'
        AND D.Activity_Date > E.Start_Date
        ) C
    WHERE E.Start_Date > '20180601'
),
RemovedAfter as
(
    --If the employee gets removed from a company before 4/1 they dont get counted. If they are removed on or after 4/1 it counts.
    SELECT Cust_ID, Emp_ID
    FROM Cust_Employee
    WHERE End_Date >= '20180401'
),
RemovedBefore as
(
    --If the employee gets removed from a company before 4/1 they dont get counted. If they are removed on or after 4/1 it counts.
    SELECT Cust_ID, Emp_ID
    FROM Cust_Employee
    WHERE End_Date <= '20180401'
)
--Positive Rules
SELECT * FROM AssignedBefore
UNION
SELECT * FROM AssignedReviewed
UNION 
SELECT * FROM RemovedBefore
--Negative Rules
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM RemovedBefore
```

Once you have this result for the tuples of Cust/Emp that need to appear in the output, you can add whatever information you need.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd approach this query would get very friendly with both common table expressions and EXISTS/NOT EXISTS.

I gathered for a given employee, if there were engagements with the customer prior to when the employee had a review with that customer, they should be ignored in the scope of that employee. For this I've implemented a common table expression (`cte_engagements_to_ignore`) to filter those out.
The results of this common table expression end up being employee / cust_data records that should be ignored.
It works by first filtering down to all the engagements, and then filtering down to just the ones where no previous review exists that happened after the employee's assignment and prior to the engagement we're comparing to.

Next up we query the employee/customer data tables and automatically include if the customer started prior to 6/1 OR if a review exists that happened after they were assigned to the employee. We then exclude if unassigned prior to 4/1 or if the engagement is one that we identified should be ignored for the given employee.

Very puzzling one, indeed!

```
WITH cte_engagements_to_ignore AS 
    ( -- filter out client engagements that happened prior to reviews
        SELECT 
            A.Emp_ID,
            B.Cust_Data_ID
        FROM Cust_Employee A 
        INNER JOIN Cust_Data B 
        ON      A.Cust_ID = B.Cust_ID
        WHERE   B.Task = 'Client Engagement' 
            AND NOT EXISTS 
                    ( -- exclude this client engagement if there was not a review for this customer prior to it
                        SELECT
                            *
                        FROM Cust_Data X1 
                        WHERE   A.Cust_ID = X1.Cust_ID
                            AND X1.Task = 'Review'
                            AND A.Start_Date < X1.Activity_Date -- review happened after assignment
                            AND B.Activity_Date > X1.Activity_Date -- review happened prior to engagement
                    )
    )
SELECT 
    A.Emp_ID,
    A.Cust_ID,
    A.Start_Date,
    A.End_Date,
    B.Activity_Date,
    B.Task
FROM Cust_Employee A 
LEFT JOIN Cust_Data B 
ON      A.Cust_ID = B.Cust_ID
WHERE   (
            -- included automatically if started before 6/1
            A.Start_Date < '2018-06-01' 
            -- or include if there is a review after assignment
        OR EXISTS 
                ( 
                    SELECT 
                        *
                    FROM Cust_Data X1 
                    WHERE   A.Cust_ID = X1.Cust_ID
                        AND A.Start_Date < X1.Activity_Date
                        AND X1.Task = 'Review'
                )
        )
        -- exclude if unassigned prior to 4/1
    AND ISNULL(A.End_Date, '2050-01-01') >= '2018-04-01'
        -- filter out engagements we identified should be ignored
    AND NOT EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT 
                *
            FROM cte_engagements_to_ignore X1 
            WHERE   A.Emp_ID = X1.Emp_ID
                AND B.Cust_Data_ID = X1.Cust_Data_ID
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this to get the various rule criteria using CTEs and then apply the logic in the final query:

```
WITH Reviews AS (
    SELECT d1.Cust_ID, 'true' AS HasActiveReview
    FROM Cust_Data d1
    INNER JOIN Cust_Data d2 ON d1.Cust_ID = d2.Cust_id
    WHERE d1.Task = 'Review' 
        AND d2.Task = 'Client Engagement'
        AND d1.Activity_Date >= d2.Activity_Date
    ),
RuleData as (
SELECT e.Cust_Emp_ID,
    (CASE WHEN e.Start_Date >= '20180601' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS StartAfter0601,
    (CASE WHEN e.End_Date <= '20180401' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) as EndBefore0401,
    COALESCE(r.HasActiveReview, 'false') as HasReview
FROM Cust_Employee e
LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews r on e.Cust_ID = r.Cust_ID)
SELECT e.Emp_id, e.Cust_id, e.Start_Date, e.end_date, MAX(d.Activity_Date) AS Activity_Date, d.Task
FROM RuleData r
INNER JOIN Cust_Employee e on r.Cust_Emp_ID = e.Cust_Emp_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Cust_Data d on e.Cust_ID = d.Cust_ID
WHERE r.EndBefore0401 = 'false'
    AND ((r.StartAfter0601 = 'true' AND r.HasReview = 'true') OR r.StartAfter0601 = 'false')
GROUP BY e.Emp_id, e.Cust_id, e.Start_Date, e.end_date, d.Task, r.Cust_Emp_ID, r.StartAfter0601, r.EndBefore0401, r.HasReview
ORDER BY e.Emp_id, e.Cust_id;
```

If you need to debug it is easy to add the rule data to end of the query to see why a row is returned:

```
WITH Reviews AS (
    SELECT d1.Cust_ID, 'true' AS HasActiveReview
    FROM Cust_Data d1
    INNER JOIN Cust_Data d2 ON d1.Cust_ID = d2.Cust_id
    WHERE d1.Task = 'Review' 
        AND d2.Task = 'Client Engagement'
        AND d1.Activity_Date >= d2.Activity_Date
    ),
RuleData as (
SELECT e.Cust_Emp_ID,
    (CASE WHEN e.Start_Date >= '20180601' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS StartAfter0601,
    (CASE WHEN e.End_Date <= '20180401' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) as EndBefore0401,
    COALESCE(r.HasActiveReview, 'false') as HasReview
FROM Cust_Employee e
LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews r on e.Cust_ID = r.Cust_ID)
SELECT e.Emp_id, e.Cust_id, e.Start_Date, e.end_date, MAX(d.Activity_Date) AS Activity_Date, d.Task, r.Cust_Emp_ID, r.StartAfter0601, r.EndBefore0401, r.HasReview
FROM RuleData r
INNER JOIN Cust_Employee e on r.Cust_Emp_ID = e.Cust_Emp_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Cust_Data d on e.Cust_ID = d.Cust_ID
WHERE r.EndBefore0401 = 'false'
    AND ((r.StartAfter0601 = 'true' AND r.HasReview = 'true') OR r.StartAfter0601 = 'false')
GROUP BY e.Emp_id, e.Cust_id, e.Start_Date, e.end_date, d.Task, r.Cust_Emp_ID, r.StartAfter0601, r.EndBefore0401, r.HasReview
ORDER BY e.Emp_id, e.Cust_id;
```

I have used 'true' and false' to represent boolean values, you could use 1 and 0 BIT if you prefer.

Running the query it returns an extra row for Cust_Id 19, returning both the 'Customer Engagement' record plus the 'Review' one.  I'm not sure why it shouldn't do this when you want both rows for Cust_Id 17 and it seems the same should apply for Cust_Id 19

```
Emp_Id,Cust_id,Start_Date,End_Date,Activity_Date,Task
4,11,2017-10-01 00:00:00.000,2018-07-31 00:00:00.000,NULL,NULL
4,15,2017-10-01 00:00:00.000,2018-04-08 00:00:00.000,2018-04-02 00:00:00.000,Review
4,17,2018-06-01 00:00:00.000,NULL,2018-06-29 00:00:00.000,Client Engagement
4,17,2018-06-01 00:00:00.000,NULL,2018-06-25 00:00:00.000,Review
4,19,2018-05-18 00:00:00.000,NULL,2018-05-25 00:00:00.000,Client Engagement
4,19,2018-05-18 00:00:00.000,NULL,2018-06-28 00:00:00.000,Review
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.

```
SELECT employee
FROM employee emp
JOIN employee-customer ecust ON ecust.empID = ecust.empID
JOIN customer cust ON cust.custID = ecust.custID and cust.Task = 'Review'
WHERE 
(emp.StartDate <= '01062019' and (emp.EndDate <= '01042019' or emp.EndDate = NULL) or 
( emp.StartDate <= cust.ActivityDate )
```